# Arduino + SIM800L Conectar ao Firebase

Tags: banco-de-dados, c++, firebase, arduino, firebase-database

Galera,

Estou montando um projeto e preciso conectar meu arduino ao firebase. Para isso estou utilizando uma SIM800L, porem meu código retornar o erro abaixo no compilador, alguém já passou por isso ou poderia me ajudar?

**Erro:
Opções de compilação alteradas, recompilando tudo In file included from C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\sketch_mar19a\sketch_mar19a.ino:7:0:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src/Firebase.h:25:18: fatal error: memory: No such file or directory
 #include 
                  ^
compilation terminated.
exit status 1 Erro compilando para a placa Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560**

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#include <Sim800l.h>

#include <TinyGPS.h>

#include <Firebase.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>
#include <FirebaseCloudMessaging.h>
#include <FirebaseError.h>
#include <FirebaseHttpClient.h>
#include <FirebaseObject.h>

#include <String.h>


//Define o Host e Senha do firebase
#define FIREBASE_HOST"testefirebase-6a04d.firebaseio.com/"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "UKMXPnz20iQlaedqkNk3wlN7RTQnar9cS2HIOHXy"

//Definindo variaveis dos pinos
int pinoLed = 5;

GPRS gprs;

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pinoLed, OUTPUT);
  Serial.println("Conectando a rede!");

  //Inicia Comunicação com firebase
  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
  digitalWrite(pinoLed, 0);

}

void loop() {
   String ledStatus = Firebase.getString("led2");
  if(ledStatus == "ligado"){
    Serial.println(ledStatus);
    digitalWrite(pinoLed, 1);
  }
  else if(ledStatus =="desligado") {
    Serial.println(ledStatus);
    digitalWrite(pinoLed, 0);
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

O A biblioteca está instalada na IDE do arduino ou esta localizada dentro da pasta do projeto? Porque aparentemente ele não está usando encontrando a *Firebase.h* lá dentro da pasta da bibliotecas da IDE.

Se estiveres usando dentro da pasta do projeto, tente colocar o include assim **#include "FirebaseArduino.h"**. Não sei se vale para o copilador do arduino, mas em outros compiladores de C++ o include com *<biblioteca.h>* indica que deve-se buscar na pasta do sistema/ide, enquanto o include com aspas na pasta do projeto ou personalizada.